# cant figur how to find a greater or less than for a variable

Tags: php

I have tried muiltiple strings of code to find the awswer please help me out, here's the code

```
    $rating = $row['rating_total'] / $row['number_ratings'];

if($rating < 2 && $rating => 1) {
$rating = ' <img src="rating.png" /> ';
  }

if($rating < 3 && $rating => 2) {
$rating = ' <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> ';
  }

if($rating < 4) && ($rating => 3) {
$rating = ' <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" />'; 
  } 
  if($rating < 5) && ($rating => 4) {
$rating = ' <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" />';
  }
   if($rating < 6) && ($rating => 5) {
$rating = ' <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> <img src="rating.png" /> ';
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Why is `$rating` getting replaced with a string?

Comment: replacing `$rating` with a string of HTML and then going on to compare it to a bunch of other numbers seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: `$rating = intval($row['rating_total'] / $row['number_ratings']); $ratingText = str_repeat(' <img src="rating.png" />', $rating);`

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with your code, I agree with everyone else, this is a bad idea. Anyways, before using >/< make sure the variable has ints, and then

```
$rating=intval($rating)

if($rating==1){$rating='<img src="" />'}
else if($rating==2){$rating='<img src="" /> <img src="" />'}
else if($rating==3){$rating='<img src="" /> <img src="" /> <img src="" />'}
```

First also confirm you are performing '/' on two integers or floats not two strings.

```
  $rating = floatval($row['rating_total']) / floatval($row['number_ratings']) ;
```

This may be unnecessary but always be **sure** if you have to find whats going wrong

And try use `echo $rating` in between to see whats going wrong.